# Se llena la memoria ejecutando una linea de macro con selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy tratando de ejecutar la siguiente macro

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver
Dim openFile As Excel.Workbook
driver.Start "Chrome"
driver.Get ("https://picizweb31.grupozfb.com/picizweb/#/home")
driver.FindElementByName("ZONAFRANCA").AsSelect.SelectByValue ("50")
driver.FindElementByName("COMPANYID").AsSelect.SelectByValue ("012")
driver.FindElementByName("LOGIN").SendKeys ("SEBVAL012")
driver.FindElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys (Sheets("GIF").Cells(10, 6).Value)
driver.FindElementByClass("Form-button").Click
```

`
Pero al momento de ejecutarse la linea:  driver.FindElementByName("ZONAFRANCA").AsSelect.SelectByValue ("50"), me sale el siguiuente error:
[image: Memoria insufciente]

Lo curioso de todo este asunto es que cuando lo hago paso a paso funciona perfecto, no se que error estoy cometiendo, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con Selenium pero cuando ejecutas código paso a paso, digamos que no avanza a la siguiente línea hasta que ha completado la anterior. Para forzar eso en tiempo de ejecución, prueba a poner un `DoEvents` antes y después de donde te levanta el error, a ver si cuela.

Comment: Hola @Esei gracias por tu consejo, la verdad pase todo el código a un modulo y listo se soluciono el problema, no se por que pero ya funciona a la perfección